# nested each loop querying wrong column name... model issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a page which displays "events" and each event has users which can be divided into groups... the models look like this-

events:

```
 has_many :users, through: :event_users
 has_many :event_users
 has_many :event_user_groups
```

event_users:

```
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :event_user_group, foreign_key: "group_id"
```

event_user_groups:

```
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :event_users
```

So in my view I want to loop through the groups and then loop through the users in each group so I can show a subheading for each group with a list of the users in that group

```
<% @event.event_user_groups.each do |group| %>

    <h4> <%= group.try(:name) %> </h4>

        <% group.event_user.each do |user| %>
             <%= user.try(:name) %>
        <% end>
<% end >
```

The problem is the SQL that gets executed for the second each loop is:

> EventWine Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "event_users".* FROM "event_users"
>   WHERE "event_users"."event_user_group_id" = $1 
>   [["event_user_group_id", 7]]

and "event_user_group_id" is not the name of the column.... it is supposed to be "group_id"

So want can I change so that the query for the nested each loop using the correct column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% group.event_user.each do |user| %>
```

Is wrong. It should be `group.event_users.each do |event_user|`. You said `event_user_groups` `has_many :event_users`. So it will link to the `event_users` table, and be plural instead of singular.

Also change `has_many :event_users` to `has_many :event_users, foreign_key: :group_id` if the column is indeed `event_users.group_id`.

You can also add

```
  has_many :users, through: :event_users
```

To `event_user_groups` to get to the users collection directly.

See the options for `has_many`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Also change `belongs_to :event_user_group, foreign_key: "group_id"` to `belongs_to :group, class_name: 'EventUserGroup'`. `foreign_key` tells you the column in the *other* table. You said your column was named `event_users.group_id` so `belongs_to` will match the field name, but since you don't have a class called `Group` you have to explicitly tell it what class it links to.

Comment: Thanks for the help, declaring the foreign_key on the wrong side of the relationship was my main problem and changing that fixed the SQL in my each loop.